# SEO for anchor link falling under headings tag

Tags: html, seo

I am working on a website on which i show restaurants according to either categories, food, etc. So I have a listing page where I list the restaurants as per the filters applied by the user.

I have a SEO question.
It is said that using heading tags`<h1>,<h2>...` tags should be used for titles, and important items.
So this is what I did.

```
...
<div class="item">
    <h1>Title of Restaurant</h1>
    <h2>Address</h2>
    <p>Description</p>
</div>
...
```

which, for design changes, was later changed to 
**[EDIT]**
As per @Guffa's response, there should be minimum `<h1>` tags possible on the page.
Since the **Title of the restaurant** is important and I want it to be recognized as a heading rather than simple text, I'll use `<h3>` for it.

```
...
<div class="item">
    <h3><a href="link to restaurant">Title of Restaurant</a></h3>
    <h4>Address</h4>
    <p>Description</p>
</div>
...
```

The scenario that `<h4>` tag has no text but rather a child node with a link.
So my question is when my page is indexed (second case), will the `<h4>` be recognized?
Or will it be completely ignored and thought of as a hyperlink?

Is filling the heading text with a very high text-indent a smart idea?
Or should i use the anchor as it is and apply a `title` attribute to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `h1` tag should be used for important information about the page, so you should really only have one on the page.

Having a listing with `h1` tags means that the spiders get conflicting information about what's important on the page, and will likely ignore all of them.

As the `h1` should be something like the title for the page, it doesn't make much sense to have a link inside it, as that link would go to the same page.

Comment: @AaditiSharma: Yes, as far as possible each page should have a unique text in the `h1` tag. If you have many pages with the same title, spiders might think that it's different versions of the same page, and ignore duplicates.

Comment: I edited the question. In case I use `<h3>` to represent the title, will this suffice?